# soap body blank when calling webservice using apache cxf api

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, cxf

Iam facing issue when appending soap body to the webservice. Iam using apache cxf api.
When calling webservice I see soap body is generated as blank.
Iam using below code :

```
 GetPDFDocumentRequest request = new ObjectFactory().createGetPDFDocumentRequest();
    request.setCrid(reference);
    request.setResourceId(confirmationId);
    request.setVersion(Integer.parseInt(version));
    request.setDocType(pdfType);
    String encryptedString  = svc().getPDFDocument(request).getDocument();
```

Although when I print values from GetPDFDocumentRequest. All values : crid, resourceid, version and doctype has value, But I dont see it appended in soap body as follows:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><env:Header xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"></env:Header><soap:Body><ns2:GetPDFDocumentRequest xmlns="http://test.fm.com/Static/interface" xmlns:ns2="https://test.fm.grp.net/style/webservices/schemas/messages" xmlns:ns3="http://test.fm.com/EventML" xmlns:ns4="http://test.fm.com/StyleML" xmlns:ns5="http://test.fm.com/odc" xmlns:ns6="https://test.fm.rbsgrp.net/test/lifecycle/schemas/types" xmlns:ns7="https://test.fm.rbsgrp.net/style/persistence/schemas/types" xmlns:ns8="http://test.fm.com/Reporting/interface" xmlns:ns9="http://test.fm.com/ConfigML"/></soap:Body>
```

Iam using below api's in maven :

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
<artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
<version>2.7.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
<artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
<version>2.7.4</version>
</dependency>
```

I even added cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs, but no success after using this also.

Code for interceptor:

```
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault;
import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.io.CacheAndWriteOutputStream;
import org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStream;
import org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStreamCallback;
import org.apache.cxf.message.Message;
import org.apache.cxf.phase.Phase;
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class LogInterceptor extends LoggingOutInterceptor {

     private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LogInterceptor.class);
    public LogInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.PRE_STREAM);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
        OutputStream out = message.getContent(OutputStream.class);
        final CacheAndWriteOutputStream newOut = new CacheAndWriteOutputStream(out);
        message.setContent(OutputStream.class, newOut);
        newOut.registerCallback(new LoggingCallback());
    }

    public class LoggingCallback implements CachedOutputStreamCallback {
        public void onFlush(CachedOutputStream cos) {
        }

        public void onClose(CachedOutputStream cos) {
            try {
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                cos.writeCacheTo(builder, limit);
                String soapXml = builder.toString();
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "SOAP XML SENT TO STYLE" + soapXml);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to see SOAP body/wrapping elements by examining the request POJO in java code. This is because if CXF wraps the requests in the SOAP body at just before sending the request at the framework level. It is transparent to the programmer and cannot be viewed in the java code.

However, if you really want to see and intercept raw message then try using "JAXWS Handlers" or their equivalent "CXF Interceptors".

More importantly, you don't really need to intercept to see SOAP body unless you need to do some special pre/post processing or massaging of data. Otherwise, just working with the service method in Java class with data being read or written to CXF wsgen created POJOs is good enough for most practical purposes.

**Update:**
I found a CXF JIRA issue with exactly the same issue as yours. **It gives the solution write at the end for your problem** - most likely I think that might be the solution for you as well. Here is the JIRA link - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-2405

Comment: I have printed this soap body in the out interceptor only. Currently my issue is soap body is blank . it should be like as mentioned in below comment

Comment: <soap:Body>
<GetPDFDocumentRequest  xmlns:ns2="http://test.fm.com/ConfigML" xmlns:ns3="http://test.fm.com/StyleML" xmlns:ns4="http://www.test.com/odc" xmlns:ns5="https://test.fm.rbsgrp.net/style/lifecycle/schemas/types" xmlns:ns6="http://test.fm.com/EventML" xmlns:ns7="https://test.fm.rbsgrp.net/style/persistence/schemas/types" xmlns:ns8="http://test.fm.com/Reporting/interface" xmlns:ns9="http://test.fm.com/Static/interface"><crid>PABFX::L151210A04E48</crid><docType>OUTCONF</docType><version>1</version><resourceId>37927215</resourceId></GetPDFDocumentRequest>
</soap:Body>

Comment: ok, can you share the code in the interceptor where you are printing the whole request (where it is printed without SOAP body)...

Comment: Also just to confirm that on the webservice side also soap body is blank. This code is working otherwise but from one of applications it is generating soap body. It is deployed in JBOSS 5.1.2.GA. It is not the issue with interceptor. Same interceptor is working fine on other application.

Comment: seems to me it is not that problem as mine. in my scenario soap body is generated parameters id, are not set. eg: crid. I think ther is some issue with jboss. because otherwise my code is working fine when called from windows service

Comment: Is there any known bug related with jboss ?

Comment: Jboss with cxf is quite common. I don't think this is something from jboss side